# I am getting an $\alpha=0$ in the GARCH(1,1) model. Is this normal and how must I interpret it?

Tags: time-series, garch

I am running a GARCH(1,1) on return data. For some data sets, I am getting an $\alpha=0$ and a $\beta$ of 0.999. Is this normal? If so how should I interpret it?

Here is my code, here j are daily returns

```
spec2<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)),mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = TRUE, arfima = FALSE),distribution.model = "std")

mod.fit.rugarch2<-ugarchfit(spec = spec2, data = as.numeric(j))
show(mod.fit.rugarch2)
```

Comment: It seems very unlikely, but not impossible. Posting your code, would definitely help to understand whether you've made a mistake or not. **Interpretation**: $\alpha$ measures how much past shocks feeds in to current volatility, $\alpha + \beta$ measures the persistence of past volatility (ie. the rate at which the "shocks" dies off). See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61824/how-to-interpret-garch-parameters).

Comment: See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113294/does-garchp-0-make-sense-at-all) and my answer there for what happens when $\alpha=0$. If that is the case, we do not need a GARCH model as volatility follows a purely deterministic trend.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. @Pleb I have added the code

Comment: @forb I cannot see any immediate problems with your code. I believe it might be a data-problem. Here are some things you can try: Your solver might have problems converging. Try and run the rugarch `ugarchfit` function on percentage log-returns (ie. multiply log-returns with 100) and see if it gives a different result. Also, there might be some outliers in your dataset (very low/high prices), which can affect your parameter estimates. You should try and remove them and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Pleb thank you. I am using percentage log-returns already. I will try to remove outliers.